# Navigation Goback without loop

Tags: windows-phone-7

I Have 2 page and the code to navigate to other page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsoluted));
```

With this code, i can go from Page1 to Page2.

When I use same code to go from Page2 to page1 (not goback):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsoluted));
```

It's ok. but i saw Page1 2 times when i use back button to exit app.

How can i fix that issue?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: is there a reason you're not using GoBack()?

Comment: I Don't Want have a navigate loop in my App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the following useful "Solving Circular Navigation in Windows Phone Silverlight Applications":-

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx

Comment: Hi! I Was try this solutuion With : WindowsPhoneSateServices.dll and WindowsPhoneLogger.dll. But it Just effect when debug app. When I exit app and use it again (in Windows phone emulator), the effect above is not work. please help me! thanks so much. Here is my Project : http://www.mediafire.com/?aix2v3w2ox4wyrd

Comment: Hi Paul! I have found my problem is: the command :
NonLinearNavigationService.Instance.Init(RootFrame);
is not at the end of App ctor. thanks so much :)